# Add an event to an existing control?

Tags: c#, events, user-controls, visual-studio-2022

Is there any way to add an event to an existing control? Without making a new one, like 'myListBox'?

The thing is, I'm trying to make a user control. It will do something regarding listboxes, but I need to make the two events that raises when an item is added or removed.

This can easily be done by making my own listbox ('myListBox') with those events, but I need to take an existing form with listboxes, add my control, and the the existing listboxes will have these two new events.

I already tried making a myListBox with those events, and then going through all the controls, putting my new  myListbox on top of the existing one, and renaming the original 'listbox1' to something like 'orgListBox1', and my new one to the old ones name ('listBox1')!
Brilliant, right? Then the app would think 'myListBox' was the original one, and everything the developer did to the original listbox would now go into mine, and have the new events I need!

Unfortunately, it does not work that way.
I understand that this is not the way to do it. I have tried looking at adding functionality to existing controls, and some can be done, but not events - as far as I can see.

So my question is:
Is there some way to add my own events to an existing control?
Or can this 'replace-the-original-with-mine' be brought to work?
Or is there a complete different solution?

Please note, it is not an option to make the developers use my new 'myListBox's instead.

Is there a solution to this?

EDIT: I'm using Visual Studio 2022, Forms.
EDIT2: This is what I have tried:

I made a new control, AnotherListBox:

```
    public class AnotherListBox : ListBox
    {
        public AnotherListBox()
        {
        }

        private const int LB_ADDSTRING = 0x180;
        private const int LB_DELETESTRING = 0x182;

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
        {
            if (message.Msg == LB_ADDSTRING)
                ItemsAdded?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            else if (message.Msg == LB_DELETESTRING)
                ItemsRemoved?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            base.WndProc(ref message);
        }

        public event EventHandler ItemsAdded;
        public event EventHandler ItemsRemoved;
    }
```

Then I tried to use it this way (where listBox1 is the original one:

```
        Control c = listBox1.Parent;
        AnotherListBox anotherListBox1 = new AnotherListBox();
        anotherListBox1.FormattingEnabled = listBox1.FormattingEnabled;
        anotherListBox1.IntegralHeight = listBox1.IntegralHeight;
        anotherListBox1.Location = listBox1.Location;
        anotherListBox1.Name = listBox1.Name;
        anotherListBox1.Size = listBox1.Size;
        anotherListBox1.TabIndex = listBox1.TabIndex;
        anotherListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        anotherListBox1.ItemsRemoved += new EventHandler(listBox1_ItemsRemoved);
        anotherListBox1.ItemsAdded += new EventHandler(listBox1_ItemsAdded);
        anotherListBox1.BringToFront();
        c.Controls.Add(anotherListBox1);
        listBox1.TabStop = false;
        foreach (string s in anotherListBox1.Items)
        {
            anotherListBox1.Items.Add(s);
        }
        listBox1.Name = "originalListBox1";
        anotherListBox1.Name = "listBox1";
```

Unfortunately, the program does not care that "listBox1" is no longer named "listBox1", and keep doing what is done to "listBox1" to the old listBox. I have tried removing and discarding the old listbox, but to no avail.

I then tried to modify the existing listBox-control using this example, which add a property to 'Label':

```
public static class LabelExtension
{
    {
        lbl.Text = text;
        lbl.Visible = true;

        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.Interval = seconds * 1000;
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
        tmr.Tag = lbl; // Stores the lbl as an Object in the Timer
        tmr.Start();
    }

    static void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer tmr = ((Timer)sender);
        Label lbl = ((Label)tmr.Tag); // Retrieves the lbl control from the Timer
        lbl.Text = "";
        tmr.Stop();
    }
}
```

This above example works fine making text fade in a label, but to add events it does not so much. It says that it doesn't like base.WndProc calls in a static, and I can not remove the static-part.

So, any suggestions?

Comment: It'll probably be helpful to clarify which UI framework you're using, and maybe show a code snippet of what you've tried.

Comment: Jimmy, you are right, my bad. I have added this information.

Comment: And now with examples of what I have tried :-)

Comment: You are down at about [page 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=active&page=19) of the Active Questions list - If your question doesn't contain *interesting* search words or offer a Bounty then it may take waiting until some who Follows specific Tags sees your question. --- Deliberately bumping your question to put it ahead of others isn't a good idea, coming back in a few days (next week) and *improving* your question is fair; you can answer some questions or explore our other sites while you wait.